# What will be the url help in scope and namespace in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, url-helper

Please tell me what will be the url helpers for the following code?

```
scope module: 'admin' do
  resources :articles, :comments
end
```

and

```
scope '/admin' do
  resources :articles, :comments
end
```

and

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :articles, :comments
end
```

Comment: You can run `rails routes` to get a list of all defined routes and their prefixes to which you can then append `_path` or `_url` as required to generate the desired path / URL.

Answer (score 1):

As per the rails guide document here - [Controller namespace and routing](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

1.

> If you want to route /articles (without the prefix /admin) to Admin::ArticlesController, you can specify the module with a scope block

the path will be like

```
GET articles_path   #index action
GET comments_path   #index action
```

2. 

> If instead, you want to route /admin/articles to ArticlesController (without the Admin:: module prefix), you can specify the path with a scope block:

this will give the following path but the controller will contain Admin:: prefix

```
GET admin_articles_path  # index action
GET admin_comments_path   #index action
```

1. with namespace, the route will prefix by admin as well as controller needs to have Admin:: module prefix

```rb
GET admin_articles_path  # index action
GET admin_comments_path   #index action
```

Comment: @AkshitThakurAK did it help you?

Answer (score 0):

Running the following commands on a console will return the available routes for your application.

```
rails routes | grep article
rails routes | grep comment
```